# Unable to set java path

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, java, paths

Hey I am trying to save my Oracle JDK path by using following command

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

And the I am saving path asL

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin"
```

And after saving when I am using `echo $PATH` I am unable to see my saved path. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin"`

not

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin"`.

You are missing `:` beetween `/usr/local/games` and `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51/bin`

Comment: i tried this also but nothing is hapening

Comment: andi am getting this error (gedit:3997): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: open your `/etc/environment` in nano using command `sudo nano /etc/environment `. Now add `:` as I said earlier and press `ctrl+o` to save and `ctrl+x` to exit. Now reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you will have to restart your X session to see the effect. I could not find much documentation on `/etc/environment`, [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-environment) explains almost nothing. Here's what I tested:

- I added `SOMETHING=hello` in `/etc/environment`
- I switch to a virtual terminal with Control Alt F1, run `echo $SOMETHING` and I correctly see `hello` so it worked
- I start a new terminal, say `xterm`, run `echo $SOMETHING` but it doesn't print anything

So it would seem that the file is used when a new login session is started. Starting a new terminal in your existing X session will not start a new login session, that's why you will see no effect.

While testing, you can use the virtual terminals, that's a lot easier than restarting X many times.